# Redux Saga: Throw and stop generator

Tags: unit-testing, redux, redux-saga

I'm writing a generator. I'm testing it with [RITEway](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=riteway&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). It checks if `window.ethereum` is defined. If its not, it should throw and stop. Basically it should satisfy the following tests:

```
describe('handle initialize Web3 saga', async assert => {
  global.window = {}

  assert({
    given: 'nothing, the window object',
    should: 'have no property called Web3',
    actual: window.web3,
    expected: undefined
  })

  const gen = cloneableGenerator(handleInitializeWeb3)()

  {
    // The important parts are in this block scope
    const clone = gen.clone()

    assert({
      given: 'window.ethereum undefined',
      should: 'throw',
      actual: clone.next().value.message,
      expected: '[WARNING]: window.ethereum has no provider!'
    })

    assert({
      given: 'nothing',
      should: 'be done',
      actual: clone.next().done,
      expected: true
    })
  }

  class Provider {}

  window.ethereum = new Provider()

  // ... more tests
})
```

Here is how I tried implementing it.

```
function* handleInitializeWeb3() {
  if (!window.ethereum) {
    yield new Error('[WARNING]: window.ethereum has no provider!')
  }
  // ... more yields
}
```

but this saga doesn't stop. The test where it `should: 'be done'` fails and the saga gives back the values from the `yield`s outside of the `if` statement. How can I have these tests pass and the saga stop when the error is thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yield`ing an error instance acts the same as yielding any other value (i.e. the generator keeps running). If you want to stop the generator you should `throw new Error(...` like in a normal function.

If for some reason you don't want to `throw` and do in fact want to yield an error instance and then stop, simply `return;` after you've `yield`ed the error.